# Recording games on the Play Magnus app

Tags: pgn

I've downloaded the Play Magnus app, and want to record the games (the PGN) I play. There is an option like 'Export game as PGN'(something like that) which allows me to copy the PGN to the clipboard while the game is in progress, but I don't seem to be able to save the PGN of the completed game since a different screen comes up. Can someone help me figure out how to copy the PGN of the **completed game?**

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misinterpreting the question, this should be possible:

As soon as the game ends (e.g. "You defeated Magnus!" appears at the bottom, if you win for instance), **don't click the arrow at the bottom** (this is what I assume is the different screen that comes up) but instead **click the list icon in the top right corner**. Click "Export game as PGN-File" and the completed game should be copied to the clipboard.